# First Day of week stuck on Sunday in any locale (Debian)

Tags: debian, xfce, locale, calendar

I'm trying to figure out why I can't have any locale working with monday set as first day of the week.

Installed locales:

```
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_US.utf8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
```

and while this looks good:

```
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" cal
    January 2019      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31
```

this one looks weird, as it should start with Monday:

```
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ LC_TIME="en_IE.UTF-8" cal
    January 2019      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31
```

Final surprise, even this one looks terribly wrong:

```
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8" cal
    Gennaio 2019      
do lu ma me gi ve sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31
```

I have already checked files @ /usr/share/i18n/locales/, and they look good (like they correctly specify the day the week should start from, Monday=2).

My /etc/default/locale looks like this:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_IE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_IE:en"
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8
```

and this is the output of "locale -a"

```
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_US.utf8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
francescos@Thinkpad-T420:~$ locale
LANG=en_IE.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_IE:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_IE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_IE.utf8"
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_IE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IE.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've already re-generated locales and rebooted the system.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your locale to the british one for the time display `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"` to get your calendar to start on monday.
You can see the configuration in that post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet)

Set it in the `/etc/default/locale` depending on your system. `/ect/locale.conf`

Comment: This is a clean way.

Answer (score 3):

## Setting `first_weekday` in locale

First, determine which time locale is in use. The system wide setting in `/etc/default/locale` may or may not be overwritten in `~/.pam_environment`.

```
$ cat ~/.pam_environment
…
LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8
…
```

Here, the locale `en_IE.UTF-8` appears to be in use.
Now, edit the locale *source* file with administrator privileges.
The editor `vim` is used here, but this can be replaced by, say `nano`.

```
$ sudo vim /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IE
```

Add the following line right before the `END LC_TIME` delimiter and save the modified locale source file.

```
first_weekday  2
```

Some also suggest adding `first_workday  2`. However, on my system this was not necessary.

Finally, regenerate the locale files with the following command:

```
$ sudo locale-gen
```

Log out and in again for this change to take effect.

Comment: This change seems to have been lost after an OS upgrade. Is there a way to make it persist? Maybe something related to `/usr/local/share/i18n/locales`? That dir doesn't exist on my Ubuntu, but I imagine I could create it and `locale-gen` would use it.

Comment: I ended up making my own locale file, putting it in `/usr/local/share/i18n/locales/`, then running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. It was quite a process and there's a bunch more setup I haven't mentioned here. If anyone knows an easier way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

try `cal -m` or `cal --monday`, see `man cal`

Comment: … where there is no such option documented or it means something quite different. 
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bsdmainutils/cal.1.en.html https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/gcal/gcal.1.en.html http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?cal+1  You should probably make it clear that your answer only applies to the `cal` from util-linux, which is not provided on the questioner's operating system.